# Looking for a working example of Core Data to CloudKit Public Database sync with delete and subscriptions working

Tags: ios, swift, database, core-data, cloudkit

After trying for many days with no success, I am posting this question here hoping someone could help me with this rather simple looking problem. I am doing this for a **Swift** project, not **SwiftUI**.

My requirement is pretty straight forward and I am puzzled why there is no clear solution to it in Apple's documentation, or anywhere else. I want on my iOS app a public and a private database syncing from the CloudKit to the app's Core Data, and vice versa.

I have gone over the WWDC videos and sample codes several times. If they were working, I wouldn't be posting my question here.

The guy in the latest WWDC2022 video is showing code from WWDC2019 video. And the code you download is different than what he is showing in the video. And this downloaded code is not only way too complicated and confusing for such a simple task, but it also doesn't deal with public database syncs and or subscriptions. Such a lousy tutorial job from Apple.

With some effort I managed to find the WWDC2019 code as well, but it doesn't compile on newer Xcode. I am using Xcode 13. I fixed it to work on Xcode. But in the end, it doesn't sync with and from CloudKit as expected.

I went over countless examples, but they are all old and obsolete. I have not seen a single example which shows the latest CloudKit screen. And most examples talk only about private database sync, which is a rather simple and straight forward procedure. Hardly any example talks about setting up subscriptions, let alone with public database. Only example of setting up public database with subscription is at Hacking With Swift website, but it doesn't talk about syncing Core Data with CloudKit, but rather directly saving and reading from CloudKit.

Apple's own examples are also only for private database syncs.

So here I am, after many days of struggle and frustration. I cherry picked working code snippets from various examples. But in the end I couldn't make things work.

I am posting my code below. When running on a device, it does create records on CloudKit. It is supposed to create subscription as well but it doesn't create them every time. And even when subscriptions are created, they don't get fired reliably. Sometimes they get fired and sometimes they don't. Is this a problem with CloudKit's Development environment? I have tried setting up multiple CloudKit containers, but this problem remains.

Also, the behaviour on Simulator and a real device is not identical. On Simulator I understand you don't receive push notifications, but even starting the app doesn't download records from CloudKit every time. So sometimes it works as expected and other times it doesn't work at all. Though the logs keep showing that they have some sort of communication going on with the CloudKit backend.

In any case, deleting a record on CloudKit doesn't delete it on the device.

Running the example provided with WWDC2022 video, is also pretty flaky. It is supposed to create Post items. Which it does, but then the syncs work very unreliably, whether I set up private database subscriptions or public. Delete still doesn't work. Notifications don't work either, though I have them set up fine in my `appdelegate`

So, is there a working solution which I can refer to? Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "PublicDB")
        
        let store = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!
        let storesURL = store.url!.deletingLastPathComponent()
        store.url = storesURL.appendingPathComponent("public.sqlite")
        store.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        store.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
        store.cloudKitContainerOptions?.databaseScope = .public
        
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        
        let database = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.xxxxxx.DemoApp").publicCloudDatabase
        let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "CD_My_Entity", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordDeletion, .firesOnRecordUpdate])

        let notification = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
        notification.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
        notification.alertBody = "There's a new change in the db."
        notification.soundName = "default"
        subscription.notificationInfo = notification

        database.save(subscription) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("<><><><><><><>")
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                print("<><><><><><><>")
            }
        }
        
        //Load the persistent stores
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (_, error) in
            guard let error = error as NSError? else { return }
            fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to load persistent stores:\(error)")
        })

        return container
    }()

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRTwF.png
```

**EDIT Sep 4 2022**
Since I posted this question almost a month ago and have been working on other parts of my app, in this one month I have noticed that the subscriptions and syncs sometimes work flawlessly and beautifully sync all devices within few seconds. And at other times they simply don't work. I have not touched the above code at all during this time as I was planning to come back to it once other parts of the app were done. Some days in the morning when I start work, I see my devices perfectly synced from the day before. So clearly it seems that the problem is with iCloud's Dev environment, not with the above code. I'll keep an eye on this behaviour until I put my app into production.

Comment: For CoreData with Public container - Refer https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10650. To create a sample project to sync from CoreData to Cloud, then create a new project and select CoreData checkbox and select CloudKit checkbox, then add capability for iCloud and add capability for Push notification. I have just tested it on the latest version of Xcode the sample project works as expected.

Comment: When sync doesn't happen reliably, look at the sql file being created and delete that folder,  quit Xcode, delete DerivedData contents, delete apps on simulator (reset it) and delete app on device and try again

Comment: Don't set `notification.alertBody` and `notification.soundName`. This is not a UI notification, it will just deliver the payload. Also ensure Push notification and background mode is enabled.

Comment: @user1046037 my question is about reliably working subscriptions with public database. The example you referred to, which as I mentioned is buggy, doesn't deal with subscriptions with public databases.

Answer (score 0):

So now that my app is in production and working perfectly fine, my observation is that the problem I posted in the question has something to do with Apple's development environment. In the production I am not seeing any issues and the code is the same as in the question above.

The issue with delete however remains. Deletes don't get synced.